# How to apply a particular django database migration in heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration, django-migrations

I uploaded my modified code with some changes in models. When I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate app` to apply the database migrations it gave me an error

`CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected (0004_auto_20150819_0827, 0008_auto_20150813_1444 in app).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'`

So when I run `heroku run python manage.py makemigrations --merge`  it gave me output:

`Created new merge migration /app/app/migrations/0009_merge.py`

Now how can apply this migration to my database ?

Comment: You should create this migration on local machine first, instead of creation on Heroku.
I meant `python manage.py makemigrations --merge`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

or to see what it's going to apply:

```
heroku run python manage.py showmigrations
```